# Help with proof with One-Point Compactification and Quotient Spaces.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I have been tasked with proving the following:

> Let $X$ be a compact, Hausdorff space, and let $U$ be a proper opens subset of $X$. Prove that $$ U^{\infty} \cong X / \left( X - U \right)$$

Note that $U^{\infty} = U \cup \left\lbrace \infty \right\rbrace$ and $X / \left(X - U \right)$ denotes $X/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $X$ given by $$x \sim x' \text{ if  and only if } x= x' \text{ or } x,x' \in X - U.$$

**My attempt so far:**

> Since $U$ is open in $X$, $X - U$ is a closed subset of $X$, and thus
> $X / \left(X - U\right)$ is a compact, Hausdorff space. Also, by a
> previous theorem, $U^{\infty}$ is compact. Now, consider the mapping
> $h : U^{\infty}  \to X/(X-U)$ given by $h(u) = p(u)$ for each $u \in
> U$ and $h(\infty)= p(X- U)$ where $p: X \to X/(X-U)$ is the natural projection. If $u, v \in U$ and $h(u) = h(v)$, then
> $u = v$, so $f$ one-to-one. Next, $h(X) = p(U) \cup p(X-U) = X/(X- U)$
> since $p$ is onto, so $h$ is onto, and hence $h$ is a homeomorphism.

I am pretty sure my logic is sound, although I do not think my proof is neither thorough nor concise enough. So, I welcome all suggestions.

Comment: Is $p$ the quotient map $X \to X/(X - U)$?

Comment: Yes, @SophieMacDonald. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to argue that $h$ is continuous. You just showed it is a bijection.

It's clearly continuous at all $u \in U$ as $U$ is open and $p$ is continuous. So show continuity at $\infty$.

Comment: dear @MichaelCook, unfortunately what you have written is not true in general. it is the case that a *continuous* bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, but it is not the case that an *arbitrary* bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is necessarily a homeomorphism. for instance consider the map $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ that swaps $0$ and $1$ and fixes all other points. this is a bijection, and $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact and Hausdorff, but is $f$ a homeomorphism? (indeed is $f$ even continuous?)

Comment: Oh darn, you are right. I forgot about that. Silly me.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I am such a moron.

Comment: @MichaelCook no worries at all, it's an easy mistake to make!! :) I think sometimes when one is applying a theorem a bit "mechanically", so to speak, it can be quite easy to misremember the hypotheses

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Here is an attempt to prove $h$ is continuous: Let $V \subseteq X/ (X-A)$ be open. If $X - A \notin V$, then $h^{-1}(V) = p^{-1}(V)$ which is open since $p$ is continuous. Otherwise $V$ can be written as $\{X - U\} \cup (V - \{ X - U\}$. Now $X/ (X - U)$ is Hausdorff, so $\{X - U\}$ is closed and thus $V - \{ X - U\}$ is open.

Comment: @MichaelCook no, do it differently.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Using neighbourhoods?

Comment: @MichaelCook where are you using the definition of the quotient topology and the compactification? When you’re not explicitly using them it cannot be correct.

Comment: @MichaelCook you need it for both cases.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $X/(X-U)$ is Hausdorff, so $\{ X - U\}$  is closed and thus $V - \{ X - U\}$ is open. $p^{-1}(V - \{ X - U\})$ is open in $X$ (definition of quotient topology)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124590/discussion-between-michael-cook-and-henno-brandsma).